# Hide/show element with a boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, visibility

I tend to have a lot of these in my code

```
if(shouldElementBeVisible)
    $element.show()
else
    $element.hide()
```

Is there any more elegant way packaged with javascript, jquery, or underscore? Ideally I want something that looks like this

```
$element.showOrHideDependingOn(shouldElementBeVisible)
```

Comment: [jQuery show or hide](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jQuery%20show%20or%20hide)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek that question happens to reference `toggle`, but its a different question

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Apparently you can just pass a boolean to the `toggle` function

```
$element.toggle(shouldElementBeVisible)
```

Comment: I recommend using `$element.toggle(!!shouldElementBeVisible)` to prevent [accidentally hitting one of the other "overloads"](https://jsfiddle.net/md944e08/), unless of course you're very sure that the variable is a boolean value.

Comment: A better option might be `$element.toggle(shouldElementBeVisible == true)`.

Comment: `"0"` and `"false"` are treated very different than `false` anyway, so I don't think that distinction really matters - even `0` would be incorrect if you want it to be hidden, since all of those set animation times but still flip visibility.

Answer (score 32):

Yes there is!

```
$element.toggle();
```

Without any parameters, `toggle` just toggles the elements visibility (I don't mean the `visibility` property) and depends on the current state of the element.

```
$element.toggle(display);
```

If you call `toggle` with a boolean parameter, element is shown if it is `true` and `hidden` if it is `false`

[source](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

Comment: I was about to mark this wrong, then I realized that the last API reference allows you to set a boolean instead of an options object.

Comment: a few lines under that: "With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements"

Comment: thats actually the opposite of what I wanted. I wanted to have the element's current state be irrelevant. The state should be based on a boolean variable.

Comment: @AakilFernandes So the variable `isShown` is not relevant to the `$element` being visible or not? But a separate variable not related to the element?

Comment: Yes, sorry I probably should of renamed `isShown` to something like `shouldElementBeVisible` to make it more obvious

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has `toggle`:  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

`$element.toggle();`

This will show the element if it's hidden, and hide it if it's shown.

Answer (score -2):

```
$element[ shouldElementBeVisible?'show':'hide' ]()
```

Comment: $element['hide'] or $element['show'] will not toggle element's class. It will return null